# Why was my post deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, moderators, self-answer, specific-answer

A few days ago I asked a question about `await`.   I got one helpful answer, which I accepted, but in the end `await` just makes it harder to read, and requires `async` keywords in nested functions.

So I posted the solution I ended up using:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12715484/50552

That got removed by a moderator just now.  There's no comment why.  It looks like the moderator decided he doesn't like my answer.

Why was this answer removed?
What qualifies the answer for moderator instead of community removal?

Comment: Wow, I have no idea. There were no flags on your answer. It *could* be due to your opening statement "Based on Reed Copsey, Servy and Stephen Cleary's answer and comments", but while I wouldn't be surprised if people had flagged your self-answer with the assumption that you meant to edit your question instead, nobody did. And as a mod I wouldn't have deleted it myself, because you clearly state that it is a solution to your problem. In any case, let me harass him for you...

Comment: (Disclaimer: I do delete low-quality posts and non-answers without necessarily having flags on the post to answer to as well, if the post is obviously spammy or low quality according to my judgement. However in this case I would *not* have deleted your answer.)

Comment: What's wrong with meta these days? 45 mins has passed and no one's called casperOne a freedom hating Nazi moderator?

Comment: @yoda That's because casperOne nowadays is a synonym of freedom hating Nazi moderator ;P

Comment: It was probably mistaken for not-an-answer, but it is one. And even when it is the wrong answer it adds some value. It ought to be undeleed, but note tht there is nothing wrong with the downvote(s).

Comment: I've undeleted your answer.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: Thanks!

Comment: @yoda - It would be funny if it was really casperOne who deleted that.

Comment: @jmort253 [It was](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12715484/revisions)

Answer (score 1):

I deleted it.

It was because of this statement:

> Based on Reed Copsey, Servy and Stephen Cleary's answer and comments
>   I've progressed to this solution:

and:

> The second Select will wait on the tasks to finish. I've added a
>   ToList() in between to prevent streaming, but it seems to work without
>   that.

To me, this looks like you are asking a follow up question; granted, there's no question mark, but there's a statement about ambiguity in what you have done (which is *not* what you did in the question), so it seems *a lot* like a new question.

Even if it's *not* a follow up question, it definitely doesn't come off as an answer to the *question* itself. So at best, it's looks like a follow up statement.  At worst, it looks like a new question. Neither of these things are an answer, hence the deletion.

If you want clarification on an answer that was given to you, the appropriate thing is to *comment on the answer*.

If you want to expand on the question that you asked, then you should *edit the question*. Either way, an *answer* that does either of these things is the wrong thing to do. There was nothing personal (like/dislike, etc) that factored into this.

I would ask that you edit the relevant follow up from your answer and either:

- Edit your existing question
- Post a new question (if the problem you have now is unrelated to the original problem)

Comment: I was half right :)